# Test Code:Error: Compile Error: Invalid type: CustomLead_c at line 9 column 14

Tags: apex, class

I am receiving "Error: Compile Error:Invalid typr; CustomLead_c at line 9 column 14".
Can any pls tell me how to fix this error.

****Code:****

public class LeadConversion {

```
public PageReference RedirecttoLead() {
    String currentLead = '/' + leadObj.Id;
    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference(currentLead);
    return pageRef;
}

 private CustomLead_c leadObj;

// The extension constructor initializes the private member
// variable acct by using the getRecord method from the standard
// controller.
public LeadConversion(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    leadObj = (CustomLead_c)stdController.getRecord();
}

public void convertLead(){

    Account acc = new Account();
    //acc.Name = leadObj.Name;
    //acc.BillingAddress = leadObj.Address;
   try 
   { 
    insert acc; 
   }
    Catch (Exception ex1)
    {

     ex1.getmessage();
    }
    Contact cc = new Contact();
    //cc.Name = leadObj.Name;
    //cc.BillingAddress = leadObj.Address;

   try 
   { 
    insert cc; 
   }
    Catch (Exception ex2)
    {

     ex2.getmessage();
    }

    Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
    //opp.Name = leadObj.Name;
    //opp.BillingAddress = leadObj.Address;

    try 
   { 
    insert opp; 
   }
    Catch (Exception ex3)
    {

     ex3.getmessage();
    }

}

}
```

Thanks,
Regards,
Lavanya.

Comment: Shouldnt it be  CustomLead__c, There is only one underscore, it should be double underscore

Answer (score 2):

You have used `CustomLead_c` instead of `CustomLead__c` in your code.
API names of custom objects end with `__c`.

Comment: thanks, i have made the changes now its working. Thanks a lot. Also tell me how to get code coverage for this.

Comment: You should write a test class invoking your controller and methods. This will help you.
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing.htm